# Mysql join and sum is doubling result

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table of revenue as

```
title_id     revenue    cost
   1            10        5
   2            10        5
   3            10        5
   4            10        5
   1            20        6                    
   2            20        6
   3            20        6
   4            20        6
```

when i execute this query

```
SELECT SUM(revenue),SUM(cost)
FROM revenue
GROUP BY revenue.title_id
```

it produces result

```
title_id     revenue    cost
   1            30        11
   2            30        11
   3            30        11
   4            30        11
```

which is ok, now i want to combine sum result with another table which has structure like this

```
title_id     interest    
   1            10        
   2            10        
   3            10        
   4            10        
   1            20                            
   2            20        
   3            20        
   4            20
```

when i execute join with aggregate function like this

```
SELECT SUM(revenue),SUM(cost),SUM(interest)
FROM revenue
LEFT JOIN fund ON revenue.title_id = fund.title_id
GROUP BY revenue.title_id,fund.title_id
```

it double the result

```
title_id     revenue    cost    interest
   1            60        22       60
   2            60        22       60
   3            60        22       60
   4            60        22       60
```

I can't understand why is it double it,please help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Its doubling because you have title repeated in fund and revenue tables. This multiplies the number of records where it matches. This is pretty easy to see if you remove the aggregate functions and look at the raw data. [See here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e6aa/10)

The way to get around this is to create inline views of your aggregates and join on the those results.

```
SELECT R.title_id, 
       R.revenue, 
       R.cost, 
       F.interest 
FROM   (SELECT title_id, 
               Sum(revenue) revenue, 
               Sum(cost)    cost 
        FROM   revenue 
        GROUP  BY revenue.title_id) r 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT title_id, 
                         Sum(interest) interest 
                  FROM   fund 
                  GROUP  BY title_id) f 
              ON r.title_id = F.title_id
```

output

```
| TITLE_ID | REVENUE | COST | INTEREST |
----------------------------------------
|        1 |      30 |   11 |       30 |
|        2 |      30 |   11 |       30 |
|        3 |      30 |   11 |       30 |
|        4 |      30 |   11 |       30 |
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e6aa/8)

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is that you have *joined* the table the first derived table from the second table without grouping it. To solve the problem, group the second table (`fund`) and join it with the first derived table using LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT  b.title_id,
        b.TotalRevenue,
        b.TotalCost,
        d.TotalInterest
FROM 
(
    SELECT   a.title_id, 
             SUM(a.revenue) TotalRevenue, 
             SUM(a.cost) TotalCost
    FROM     revenue a
    GROUP BY a.title_id
) b LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT   c.title_id, 
             SUM(a.interest) TotalInterest
    FROM     fund c
    GROUP BY c.title_id
) d ON b.title_id = d.title_id
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two rows for each title_id in revenue table.